# Concatenate object field with variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, concatenation

I'm building an object in javascript to store data dynamically.

Here is my code :

```
var id=0;
function(pName, pPrice) {
    var name = pName;
    var price = pPrice;
    var myObj = {
        id:{
            'name':name,
            'price':price
        },
    };
    (id++); // 
    console.log(myObj.id.name); // Acessing specific data
}
```

I want my `id` field to be defined by the `id` variable value so it would create a new field each time my function is called. But I don't find any solution to concatenate both.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and access dynamicly named fields using the square bracket syntax:

```
var myObj = {};
myObj['id_'+id] = {
  'name':name,
  'price':price
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
var myObj = {};
myObj[id] = {
     'name':name,
     'price':price
};

console.log(myObj[id]name); // Acessing specific data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[]` to define the dynamic property for particular object(myObj), something like

```
var myObj = {};
myObj[id] = {'nom':nom, 'prix':prix};
```

**Example**

```
function userDetail(id, nom, prix) {
    var myObj = {};
    myObj[id] = {'nom':nom, 'prix':prix};
    return myObj;   
}

var objA = userDetail('id1', 'sam', 2000);
var objB = userDetail('id2', 'ram', 12000);
var objC = userDetail('id3', 'honk', 22000);

console.log(objA.id1.nom); // prints sam
console.log(objB.id2.nom); // prints ram
console.log(objC.id3.prix);// prints 22000
```

[**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X7MW3/)**]